# Can I define models in a django project directory?

Tags: django

I started a django project (`startproject`) and then I created an app (`startapp`). Can I define models in my project directory and refer to them in my app code?

Comment: Generally no: you should always put models in your apps. Is it *possible*? I don't know, but it'd be ridiculous to try.

Answer (score 0):

```
from yourapp.models import Yourmodel
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking to import models defined in my project dir, not my app dir.